# how to get vue draggable moved item

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I am using [this](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) to implement drag-drop in my vue app. Lets my array is:

```
lists: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
]
```

I want to get the element object from the list after finishing the drop event. For example, I am moving the `Item 1` item. After finishing the drag-drop, I want to get the print of which item has been moved. So, I want to get the output:

`{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }`

To get that, I have used `@end`:

```
      <draggable 
          class="list-group" 
          ghost-class="moving-card" 
          :list="lists" 
          group="my-group"
          @end="finish($event, lists)"
      >
```

And at `finish` function, I would like to get the desired output: `{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }` from my `<v-list v-for="list in lists"></v-list>`. So, what to do at this function?

```
     finish (evt, draggedList) {
        // console.log('finished')
        // desired output (if item 1 has been moved):
        // { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }
      }
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/oNpWxWy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@change="finish"` then change your method:

```
finish (item) {
  console.log(item.moved.element) // { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' }
}
```

RTM: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events part which mentions `change` event.

Comment: what if I have 2 dopping containers? I have updated my codepen. So, each time an item moved, two prints have happened. One is the desired output and another is `''`. Is there any way to get the output only for one droppable container?

Comment: your pen seems to be working, i.e not printing 2 in console

Comment: It seems tough to me to raise the issue in codepen. I am accepting the answer for now. Maybe, I will come up with a new question with the more clear demo.